# Re-factor common code between if and else if

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have an if...else if statement as follows:

```
  If(x > y && order.invoice != 1)
    {
       DoSomething();
       x = x + y;
    }
     else if(order.invoice == 1)
     {
       x = x + y;
     }
```

Is there a better way to re-factor this. I kind of not feeling well having x = x + y in both if and else if.

Comment: For anyone attempting to solve this, 4 people have tried and made the same mistake and had to delete their answer. Please do a sanity check before answering, `x = 1`, `y = 2`, `order.invoice = 2` should cause `x` to **not** be modified.

Comment: I can't help feeling it's rather a logic issue with the conditions themselves, than a refactor-only issue. If a co-worker showed me this, I would say: "Tell me what you are trying to achive. Then, we can go into refactoring"

Comment: I think we need more context. There is probably a very nice way to refactor this but more context would help make it better.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (order.invoice != 1 && x > y) {
    DoSomething();
}
if (order.invoice == 1 || x > y) {       
   x = x + y;
}
```

Comment: How do we know that 2 is a valid number though? This is what I mean about context.

Comment: Ah, irony, the cruel mistress. (Simon is responding to a comment that is now deleted)

Answer (score 0):

You can either do the assignment twice or do one of the if statements twice.  This calculation is simple enough that I wouldn't worry about it.

It can be shortened as such, though:

```
if(x > y && order.invoice != 1)
    {
       DoSomething();
       x += y;
    }
     else if(order.invoice == 1)
     {
       x += y;
     }
```

One more option could be to use an flag to see whether or not to increment, but you still have the same tug-of-war between complexity and single calls vs. simplicity and semi-redundant code.

```
bool increment = false;

if(x > y && order.invoice != 1)
    {
       DoSomething();
       increment = true;
    }
     else if(order.invoice == 1)
     {
       increment = true
     } 

if (increment) { x += y; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof/systematic way to refactor it. Start with:

```
if (x > y && order.invoice != 1)
{
    DoSomething();
    x = x + y;
}
else if (order.invoice == 1)
{
    x = x + y;
}
```

So the question is, what set of inputs leads to `x = x + y`? Well:

```
x = x + y
<=> (x > y && order.invoice != 1) ||
    (!(x > y && order.invoice != 1) && order.invoice == 1)
<=> (x > y && order.invoice != 1) ||
    ((x <= y || order.invoice == 1) && order.invoice == 1)
<=> (x > y && order.invoice != 1) ||
    ((x <= y && order.invoice == 1) || (order.invoice == 1 && order.invoice == 1)
<=> (x > y && order.invoice != 1) ||
    ((x <= y && order.invoice == 1) || order.invoice == 1)
<=> (x > y && order.invoice != 1) ||
    order.invoice == 1
<=> (x > y || order.invoice == 1) && (order.invoice != 1 || order.invoice == 1)
<=> (x > y || order.invoice == 1)
```

Thus it's equivalent to

```
if (x > y && order.invoice != 1)
{
    DoSomething();
}
if (x > y || order.invoice == 1)
{
    x = x + y;
}
```

You can also use a truth table

```
x > y | order.invoice == 1  |   x = x + y
F     | F                   |   N
F     | T                   |   Y
T     | F                   |   Y
T     | T                   |   Y
```

which again gives you

```
x = x + y
<=> !(x <= y && order.invoice != 1)
<=> x > y || order.invoice == 1
```

Lastly, I disagree with this sort of refactoring unless it actually makes the code more understandable.
Saving lines of code doesn't mean you made the code more readable (and therefore does not make it
obviously more maintainable)